Redirect NLog logging output to file specified by the logger
I want all messages to go to all.log file and if logSource property is set then message should also go to logSource file. If I uncomment the when filter then the logSource file is not created. I added when filter so it will include only message that had logSource set to non-null value.
Code
internal class Program
{
    private static readonly Logger _log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var logEvent = LogEventInfo.Create(LogLevel.Info, null, "message");
        logEvent.Properties["logSource"] = "Program";
        _log.Log(logEvent);

        _log.Info("This message should not be in the log since logSource is not set.");
    }
}

NLog.config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog
  xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  autoReload="true">

  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="fileInfo" fileName="all.log" 
        layout="${longdate}|${level}|${event-properties:logSource}"
      />
    <target xsi:type="File" name="fileInfoSource" fileName="${event-properties:logSource}.log" 
       layout="${longdate}|${level}|${event-properties:logSource}"
    />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="fileInfo"/>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="fileInfoSource">
      <filters>
        <!--when condition="not isset('${event-properties:logSource}')" action="Ignore" /-->
      </filters>
    </logger>
  </rules>
</nlog>


NLog v5 introduces a breaking for filters to  have defaultAction="Ignore". See also LoggingRule Filters DefaultAction changed to FilterResult.Ignore

Instead of inventing your own LogSource then I really recommend that you make use of the existing NLog Logger-name (Aka. Logger-category in Microsoft ILogger)

Where does not isset come from? See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/When-filter and https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages

@RolfKristensen, the example I gave is just an example to understand why the log is not created.The LogSource is dynamic in my applicatoin and is set by user in realtime. Can you specifiy how to I configure the NLog.config to achieve what I need?

LogSource would then be the name of the Logger that user created dynamically at runtime. Ex. var logger = NLog.LogManger.GetLogger(logSource)

Alternative approach using WithProperty together with special Logger-Name for file-target redirection:
internal class Program
{
    private static readonly Logger _log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private static readonly Logger _logSource = LogManager.GetLogger("LogSource");

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetLogSource("Program").Info("Message redirected to special place");        
        _log.Info("This message goes to the default place"):
    }

    static Logger GetLogSource(string logSource)
    {
        // Consider storing in class-variable when logSource is static
        return _logSource.WithProperty("LogSource", logSource);
    }
}

NLog.config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog
  xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  autoReload="true">

  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="fileInfo" fileName="all.log" />
    <target xsi:type="File" name="fileInfoSource" fileName="${event-properties:logSource:whenEmpty=MissingSource}.log" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="LogSource" minlevel="Info" writeTo="fileInfoSource" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="fileInfo" />
  </rules>
</nlog>


Seems like a good approach. But, as stated in the post, I want all messages to go to all.log file and if logSource property is set then message should also go to logSource file. In the example above GetLogSource("Program").Info(...) doesn't write to all.log

@theateist Not sure I understand. You just have to access the LogSource-Logger by always calling GetLogSource (Maybe keep it as private member in separate class, with only static GetLogSource-public-method). Notice you cannot protect yourself from developers, but only show them the recommended path.

Anything logged should go to all.log whether you do GetLogSource("Program").Info(...) or _log.Info(...) or anything else. So, when you do GetLogSource("Program").Info(...) it will go to all.log and, since ${event-properties:logSource is not empty, it should ALSO go to ${event-properties:logSource}.log

@theateist Have updated my answer and removed finalMinLevel="Off", so all output will also reach all.log

It did the job! I was thinking is there an option to just ignore the message if logSource property is ont set instead of redirecting to MissingSource.log?

MissingSource.log is just there for troubleshooting, since one will always use GetLogSource(...) to acquire a valid Logger. But yes if you like complicate things, then you can play with https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/When-filter . Ex: <when condition="'${event-properties:logSource}' != ''" action="Log" />

Maybe create a special Logger for you special LogEvents:
internal class Program
{
    private static readonly Logger _log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetLogSource("Program").Info("Message redirected to special place");        
        _log.Info("This message goes to the default place"):
    }

    static Logger GetLogSource(string logSource)
    {
        // Consider storing in class-variable when logSource is static
        return NLog.LogManager.GetLogger($"LogSource.{logSource}");
    }
}

NLog.config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog
  xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  autoReload="true">

  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="fileInfo" fileName="all.log" />
    <target xsi:type="File" name="fileInfoSource" fileName="${logger.shortname=true}.log" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="LogSource.*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="fileInfoSource" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="fileInfo" />
  </rules>
</nlog>


But you specify explicitly .Program as source. In my case the source is dynamic. The whole LogSource.Program should not be there. The name is created in realtime when a user creates a plugin and give it a name. The plugin name would be used as the source. ${event-properties:logSource} does the job, but now I need that  only when logSource propery is set then it goes to matching ${event-properties:logSource}" file

@theateist Updated example to show that LogManager.GetLogger(loggerName) can be used dynamically.
